# Sending python objects to node.js via socket.io

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io

Ok so what I'd like to do is have a game written in python and for all the multiplayer to be handled socket.io just because these are two things I'm fairly familiar with and I wanna keep possibilities for a web version or web app for the game open

So what I'm wondering is, how exactly do I do this and would it be better to embed a javascript parser on the client side or contact node.js from python directly

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - do you want to have Python code execute on the client side? That would be quite challenging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Python objects are simple enough (not instances of classes, say), just send a JSON representation (`json.dumps()`) of them to the socket.io side. I am assuming you can parse JSON on the client side if needed.

Comment: Yeah that would work, except how do I create the json, send it to the server, and receive it?

Comment: Create: `json.dumps` on the Python side. Send: what I did was add a REST part to my server, and then use `requests` from Python. I suppose you could also use one of Python socket.io clients.